# Moq unit test with It.IsAny<DateTime>() fails

Tags: c#, moq

I'm using Moq to write the unit tests for a project, and one of the tests is failing when I try to verify that a DateTime property is assigned a value. Here's my Verify (which fails):

```
        _mockTaskContext.Verify(context => context.TaskQueue.AddObject(It.Is<TaskQueueItem>(
            task_queue => task_queue.TaskCode == (int)TaskCode.MyTask
                    && task_queue.ClientID == ExpectedClientID
                    && task_queue.JobNumber == It.IsAny<int>()
                    && task_queue.Requester == String.Empty
                    && task_queue.JobStatus == (int)JobStatus.Submitted
                    && task_queue.TimeQueued == It.IsAny<DateTime>()
                    && task_queue.TimeStarted == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
                    && task_queue.TimeStopped == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
                    && task_queue.TaskParameters == expectedTaskParam
            )), Times.Once());
```

If I comment out the expectation on `task_queue.TimeQueued` then the test passes, without making any other changes to my test. Also, if I change the requirement on either `TimeStarted` or `TimeStopped` from `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)` to `It.IsAny<DateTime>()`, the test fails. I've run the code under test outside the unit test with the actual implementation instead of a mocked repository, and `TimeQueued` is being assigned its value correctly. Any idea why `It.IsAny` doesn't seem to work correctly for `DateTime` properties, or am I setting up my expectations incorrectly?

Update: I'm using It.IsAny() in other tests without any problem, but this test is still failing. I think it might be because this is inside the It.Is lambda expression, but I don't know how I would work around that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure the `It.IsAny<>()` syntax must be used within the scope of the mock object. In this case when you use `Setup` and the mock arguments directly. This is because the mock object is in recording mode capturing the values you pass into arguments so

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Foo(It.IsAny<Bar>()));
```

will process the arguments when the Setup line is executed.

However in your example you are trying to use `It.IsAny<>()` from within the delegate to verify an argument passed in matches. When this occurs the mock is not recording but in the process of being used as a result of the object under test (which is much later).

So `someValue == It.IsAny<DateTime>()` cannot evaluate to true as the return of the `IsAny` method must return a matching value for it to be true. I expect that `It.IsAny<int>()` also does not work.

My suggestion is that you will have to match either exact values or in this case match a range of dates

```
&& IsInRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue, task_queue.TimeQueued)
```

where `IsInRange` simply another method you have for checking a value is between 2 min and max bounds.

Comment: I think you might have misread my code, I'm not using a callback. Actually, since I posted this, I've restructured my tests and no longer do a Setup unless I need to return something, it now uses strictly a Verify(...), so I'll update my question. And the It.IsAny<int>() does work just fine, but if I try to replace the String.Empty with It.IsAny<string>() it fails.

Comment: The delegate used within `It.Is<TaskQueueItem>` gets called not when the Setup on the mock is called but when the code under test runs. What I was trying to say is that using `It.IsAny<>` can only  be used when Setup is being called and not sometime later. I did a little test and using `It.IsAny<int>()` did fail. Perhaps the int value for you is 0 in this case.

Comment: You are correct! The int value that was checked against It.IsAny<int>() is assigned in the database, so it would be 0 in my test. Your mention of Callbacks put me on the right track, I realized what I really want here is probably 2 unit tests, 1 to check that the Add and SaveChanges() methods are called (behavior verification) and a separate unit test to verify the values that get assigned are correct (state verification). Thanks for setting me down the right path!