# Why does Moq setup/verify matcher fail when It.Is...() is called from anonymous function

Tags: c#, moq

I ran into some strange behavior when attempting to simplify the creation of a rather complex expression tree for Setup/Verify matching with moq.

Assume I am mocking the simple interface defined below

```
public interface IService
{
    int Send(int value);
}
```

The following code represents 5 tests. One test for each of the `mockSender.Setup(...)`. Can anyone explain why the tests marked as failing do fail?

```
[Test]
public void TestInlineSetup()
{
    const int expected = 5;
    var mockSender = new Mock<IService>(MockBehavior.Loose);

    //passes
    mockSender.Setup(s => s.Send(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expected);

    //fails
    var sendMatch = It.IsAny<int>();
    mockSender.Setup(s => s.Send(sendMatch)).Returns(expected);

    //passes
    mockSender.Setup(s => s.Send(SendMatchFromMethod())).Returns(expected);

    //fails
    var sendMatch = SendMatchFromMethod();
    mockSender.Setup(s => s.Send(sendMatch)).Returns(expected);

    //fails (this is somewhat contrived, but I have reasons for wanting to curry this)
    mockSender.Setup(s => s.Send(SendMatchFromCurriedMethod()())).Returns(expected);

    Assert.That(mockSender.Object.Send(expected), Is.EqualTo(expected));
}

public static int SendMatchFromMethod()
{
    return It.IsAny<int>();
}

public static Func<int> SendMatchFromCurriedMethod()
{
    return () => It.IsAny<int>();
}
```

Edit: I know about Mock.Of<..>(..) and normally prefer to use it but in this case it is not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem stems from the way Moq tries to parse the supplied expression tree to create a parameter matcher. You can find the source here:-

http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/MatcherFactory.cs

Referring to the source:-

- `It.IsAny<int>` matchers are detected by compiling and executing the expression that is passed as the parameter and looking for any matches (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/MatcherFactory.cs#84)).
- The above step only takes place for method calls and member accesses

So with that in mind....

1. Second test fails because the `It.IsAny<int>` method has been evaluated outside of the matcher factory. As such you have a MemberAccess expression to 0.
2. Third test passes because `SendMatchFromMethod` is treated as a method call expression and the call is evaluated inside the MatcherFactory.
3. Fourth test fails for the same reason as the second, the function has already evaluated and Moq can't detect you've actually called `It.Is<Any>`
4. Fifth test fails because the Expression is treated as a Function Invocation and Moq does not perform the matcher check for this type of expression.

The fourth test, to be honest, should pass and it just seems an oversight that its been left off, probably just because it's a bit of an edge case.

Finally `Match.Create<T>` or `MatchAttribute` can be used to deal with complex predicates, perhaps they might fit your use case?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be very similar to a situation I ran into a while ago: [Moq unit test with It.IsAny<DateTime>() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5460526/310112)

The issue seems to be with when `It.IsAny<int>()` gets evaluated. With the 2 tests that pass, it's getting evaluated inside of `Setup(...)`, which works fine. In the first 2 tests that fail, it's getting evaluated outside the scope of `Setup(...)`, so it fails to evaluate correctly. What's probably getting stored in your variable is the result of `It.IsAny<int>()`, which will be the default value for an `int` (`0`).

I don't know the exact reason why the last test would fail, but it could be either that as an optimization your static `Func<int>` gets evaluated before `Setup(...)` executes, or it could be that it gets evaluated after `Setup(...)`, but either way it's happening outside of `Setup(...)`.

Comment: Correct, you cannot use It.IsAny<> out side the lambda expression of the setup or verify