# Inspect Moq Call parameters so far

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, optional-parameters

I have an interface that includes

```
string Foobar(string one, string two, string three = null, string four = null);
```

I have setup moq as such

```
var inputType1 = It.is<string>(x=>x=="1111");
var moqedInterface = new Mock<SomeInterface>();
moqedInterface
    .setup(x=>x.Foobar(inputType1,null,null,null)
    .returns("hiya");
```

Then I call

```
string result = moqedInterface.Foobar("1111", null); //no optional parameters used
```

this interface will often be called without the optional parameters in practice and the tests should account for and mirror that usage. both for accuracy and for readability.

but when i try to verify or check the result

```
Assert.NotNull(result); //fails
moqedInterface
   .Verify(x=>x.Foobar(It.is<string>(x=>x=="1111"), null, null, null),Times.Once); //fails
```

While i suspect that Mock<> may be defaulting optional parameters to nonnull values like an empty string. I have no verification of this. 
While i could test that specific theory and any others on a trial basis, I have no way to simply check what was sent in instead.

since Moq stores the input parameters somewhere for later verification, I should be able to look somewhere in the object to check what was sent in so far, correct? Where in the Moq object can i look to find the parameters it has been called with so far while debugging?

And further what is the default behaviour of Moq on optional parameters? will parameters still default to their expected values or does Moq not support this functionality yet?

I would assume that I could find it in the inspector, but after a bit of looking i do not see it.

Answer (score 0):

While the question and situation is different

I found my answer here:

[Why does Moq setup/verify matcher fail when It.Is…() is called from anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987257/6307037)

> ...test fails because the It.IsAny method has been evaluated outside of the matcher factory. As such you have a MemberAccess expression to 0.

Moq will implement the default the optional parameters correctly and the real issue is that It.Is<> must be used within the setup function.

So instead of

> ```
> var inputType1 = It.is<string>(x=>x=="1111"); 
> //bad. evaluated outside of the MatcherFactory
> moqedInterface
>     .setup(x=>x.Foobar(inputType1,null,null,null)
>     .returns("hiya");
> ```

This will work

> ```
> moqedInterface
>     .setup(x=>x.Foobar(It.is<string>(x=>x=="1111"),null,null,null)
>     .returns("hiya");
> ```

Further, to inspect a Mock for the parameters that have been sent in so far. you should be able to check here:

```
moqedInterface.Invocations
```

however my particular version of Moq does not have this field visible for me in the inspector.